# Find All images on a Page using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How can i find all image links using "preg_replace"? I've hard time understanding how to implement regex

what I've tried so far:

```
$pattern = '~(http://pics.-[^0-9]*.jpg)(http://pics.-[^0-9]*.jpg)(</a>)~';
$result = preg_replace($pattern, '$2', $content);
```

Comment: for better understanding add examples... one example link that you currently have and one that you want...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php

Comment: Regexes are not the ultimate solution for everything.

Comment: @nhahtdh is right, you should use SAX or DOM and XPath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`preg_replace()`, as the name suggests, replaces something. You want to use `preg_match_all()`.

```
<?php
// The \\2 is an example of backreferencing. This tells pcre that
// it must match the second set of parentheses in the regular expression
// itself, which would be the ([\w]+) in this case. The extra backslash is
// required because the string is in double quotes.
$html = "<b>bold text</b><a href=howdy.html>click me</a>";

preg_match_all("/(<([\w]+)[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/\\2>)/", $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $val) {
    echo "matched: " . $val[0] . "\n";
    echo "part 1: " . $val[1] . "\n";
    echo "part 2: " . $val[2] . "\n";
    echo "part 3: " . $val[3] . "\n";
    echo "part 4: " . $val[4] . "\n\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

another easy way to find all images link from web page, use simple html dom parser

// Create DOM from URL or file

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');
```

// Find all images

```
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
echo $element->src . '<br>';
```

this is so simple way to get all image link from any webpage.

Comment: +1. Definitely the way to go if you are interested by more complex structures in a web page.